# Implementing FCM in android app and got dupilcation errors

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I making the android app, in my app i implement the FCM, if i add the FCM libraries then i got the duplication errors 
my libraries is:

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
>     implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.71'
>     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
>     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
>
> And the error is:
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzft found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
> ```
>
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfx found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfy found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfz found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzga found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgb found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgc found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgd found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzge found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgf found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgg found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgh found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgi found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgj found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgk found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgl found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgm found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgn found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgo found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-16.0.5-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.3-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.3) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.3-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.3) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>       Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.3-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.3) and
>   play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)
>
> ```
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
>  So guys please help me to resolve this error
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't  need to add the Android library com.google.firebase:firebase-core. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics. Now, to use Analytics or any of the Firebase products that require or recommend the use of Analytics, you need to explicitly add the Analytics dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2.

Please visit there for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup